# Running tensorflow on top of Keras with CPU on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm

I have installed Tensorflow and Keras with an Anaconda installation on Windows 10. I´m using an Intel i7 processor. It takes 40 minutes to train 4000 data samples of a CSV file and I´m trying to perform a LSTM RNN predictive analytics on this data.

Is this an expected compile time using CPU? Can we make it faster using cpu or switching to GPU?

Comment: What size is the datafile? Can you post your code?

Comment: its 139kb and i followed the same technique as per the below url http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-network-python/

Comment: LSTMs are notorious for their slow training time and depending on your specific LSTM structure they tend to involve a lot of elements, so graph compilation might take some time as well (still, with any real training, the training time will take very significantly longer than graph compile).

Yes, training on a GPU will make things a lot faster. There are probably some things that you can do to make it faster on a CPU as well.

Comment: If you have to stay with a CPU, one thing would be to build TensorFlow locally with flags to enable all the extra features of your CPU. I compiled mine with SSE based floating point math, SSE4.2, AVX and FMA4. It did noticeably sped my training times, your results may vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this does seem like a reasonable amount of time for your code to run when you're training using only a CPU. If you used a NVIDIA GPU it would run much faster.

However, you might not be using every core on your CPU; if you are, it might run faster. You can change the number of threads that Tensorflow uses by running

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=NUM_THREADS))
```

If you set the number of threads equal to those provided by your CPU, it should run faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response so should i add this code in my code before i start compilation ?

Comment: Yes, that would be my suggestion. Basically, when you create the `tf.Session` variable, adjust the config to include the `intra_op_parallelism_threads=NUM_THREADS` line. If you post your code I can help you with that.

Comment: For some reason iam not able to post my complete code but if you refer this link , i used the same code http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-network-python/ before the comments section

Comment: and iam using intel core i7 6600U CPU @2.60 GHz 2.81GHz

Comment: If you're using Keras, then it should automatically use every thread, so you won't need to do that. I would monitor your CPU usage as you run the code, however, to make sure that that is the case.

Comment: can you please guide me to check the CPU usage and identify the issue ? or let me know what exactly should i check in CPU usage ?

Comment: Nice suggestion, although at least in my limited experience, TF does a pretty good job at detecting and using all cores.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I doubt that OP will get much of a speedup with that.

Comment: Sure thanks a lot for your help, anyways since iam using Keras i need not to exclusively set this thread as it takes care by itself, i reduced the no of epochs , may be the model seems to be overfit, it works fine after reducing the number of epochs. Thanks again for help :)

Comment: You might want to use the `EarlyStopping` callback: https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping